# passing an id and a class to a js method

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is working fine, But i want to pass the class name(row1) and the id (xyz) as a variable to the calculateSum method, can anyone help me with this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".row1").each(function() { 
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });
 });

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;                                
    $(".row1").each(function() {        
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    }); 
    $("#xyz").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id and class are just strings that jQuery then uses to search the DOM. Just passing them as arguments to your function should do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var row = ".row1";
    var id = "xyz";
    $( row ).each(function() { 
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum( row, id );
        });
    });
 });

function calculateSum( row, id ) {
    var sum = 0;                                
    $( row ).each(function() {        
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    }); 
    $( "#"+ id ).html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```